# php echo to html parsing issues

Tags: php, html, parsing, xampp, localhost

I was recently asked to take part in a certain project that, for now, aims to parse a chunk of HTML code to PHP . Using a certain website that I have been assigned, I went through inspect element to complete my code's missing parts. The actual aim is  to spit out (using echo) some certain data on localhost, without them being stored into a database or anything relevant. Attached is the html and PHP code in a few printscreens (couldnt upload the raw codes, dunno why). Thanks in advance!

Php code:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Website link to scrap
$website = 'https://www1.gsis.gr/webtax3/etak/faces/main.jspx?_adf.ctrl- 
state=16kjeyshcz_4&_afrLoop=70130840737831';

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($website, false, null, 0);

//$html =  str_get_html('<html><body><div id="pt1:r1:0:t3::db">Hello</div> 
<div class="xx8">Goodbye</div></body></html>');
//$ret = $html->find('.xx8', 0)->plaintext;
if (is_array($html)) {
  foreach($html->find('div[class=xx8]')->outertext as $data) {
    echo $data->outertext;
  }
}
?>
```

HTML code (via inspect element, where Δεν βρεθηκαν γηπεδα is the custom text of the page i told you about):

```
<div id="pt1:r1:1:t3::db" class="xx8" 
style="position:relative;width:100%;overflow:hidden" _afrcolcount="30"><table 
class="xxb xy3" style="table-layout:fixed;position:relative;width:2097px;" 
cellspacing="0" _totalwidth="2097" _selstate="{}" _rowcount="0" _startrow="0"> 
<colgroup span="30"><col style="width:80px;"><col style="width:110px;"><col 
style="width:105px;"><col style="width:105px;"><col style="width:105px;"><col 
style="width:75px;"><col style="width:35px;"><col style="width:50px;"><col 
style="width:55px;"><col style="width:80px;"><col style="width:65px;"><col 
style="width:65px;"><col style="width:55px;"><col style="width:95px;"><col 
style="width:65px;"><col style="width:55px;"><col style="width:75px;"><col 
style="width:75px;"><col style="width:60px;"><col style="width:60px;"><col 
style="width:60px;"><col style="width:60px;"><col style="width:50px;"><col 
style="width:50px;"><col style="width:60px;"><col style="width:50px;"><col 
style="width:62px;"><col style="width:125px;"><col style="width:55px;"><col 
style="width:55px;"></colgroup></table>Δε βρέθηκαν γήπεδα.</div>
```

Comment: Please include the code directly in  your question not as images.

Comment: @Dave i do it. Sorry for that iam new on stackoverflow iam so sorry